# How to make "accessible without account" link of my profile with tag?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

For example this links works for me

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3ame%20[accessibility]

But I want to send a link to friend who doesn't have SO account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Me* refers to the currently logged in user. When I follow your link, I see *my* posts in the [accessibility](/questions/tagged/accessibility) tag rather than *yours*. So, if you wish your friend to see *your* posts, replace the "me" with your user ID:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A84201+%5Baccessibility%5D

Comment: thanks man. but same technique not working with this site http://uxexchange.com/

Comment: @Jitendra: It appears that that site doesn't implement the "user:ID" search option (and probably a few others — when I enter an empty string in the search field, it does not take me to the "advanced search options" page, as it would on SE 2.0 sites). I'm afraid you'll have to go with Google: http://www.google.com/search?q=%22jitendra+vyas%22+site%3Auxexchange.com

Comment: Is there idea to get search with one specfic tag only

Comment: @Jitendra: actually, yes — thanks to the fact that at the bottom of every question there are the words "Browse other questions tagged *tag1*, *tag2*, *tag3* ". So, you can limit the Google search to questions tagged "accessibility" by adding the string '"tagged accessibility" OR "tagged *** accessibility"' to your query, like so: http://www.google.com/search?q="jitendra+vyas"+"tagged+accessibility"+OR+"tagged+%2A+accessibility"+site%3Auxexchange.com